# Syntax Error When Making Python Chatbot Using Conditional

Tags: python

Error comes up here in line six:

```
import time
askingage=input("Are you over the age of 18? ").lower()
if askingage == "yes":
    {
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Wow, you're a fully mature adult!")
```

Comment: Why is there a ```{```. In python, ```{}``` are not used for separating ```if...else``` blocks. Instead, indentation is used. Please see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much, a friend put them for me to try to fix the issue. But even before I put them, there was a syntax issue. I am very new at coding so thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's a very standard\simple code at least I suggest you to explore further way to prevent user inputs errors - such as: define a list of accepted answer (only "yes" seems a bit too restrictive), and prevent the routine goes bananas with a try\catch (my example is just vanilla but you can easily add further checks to prevent the user give undesidered answers).
Also, time.sleep(2) is affecting UX, I suggest to use lower (or zero) pauses for such basic questions. If you'd like to prompt until a right answer is given, explore while loops.

good luck with your implementation and keep struggling! it's the best way to learn

```
import time
accepted = ["yes", "y", "sure"]
askingage=input("Are you over the age of 18? ").lower()

try:
    if askingage in accepted: 
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Wow, you're a fully mature adult!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you need to be 18 at least to proceed.") 
except Exception as e:
    print ("Sorry, something went wrong there. Can you Try again?")
```